# dynamic reference in VBA Index function

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to dynamically apply below INDEX function for two ranges where one range should be dependent on an iterator `i`.

Could anyone help how to write that down instead of my code example (only the Index part with the reference, please)?

```
With ActiveSheet
For i = 1 to 5
    .Range("c" & i & ":I" & i & "") = [INDEX(EURbased!C5:I5 * EURbased!C4:I4,0)]
Next
End With
```

I would like to use iterator i instead of the `"5"` in `EURbased!C5:I5`

Comment: use Offset() function

Comment: @iDevlop, could you pls show a short example how in this case?

Comment: I can't give you an example because I don't understand what exactly you want to do. Looks like you want to copy 15 cells into A3:C3

Comment: @Al_Iskander - can you put a screenshot of what you would like to achieve?

Comment: I edited the code. Now I would like to use iterator i instead of the "5" in EURbased!C5:I5.

Comment: @Vityata, I cannot give you a screenshot. But I would like to generate a range where each cell value is the result from a multipilciation from each cell from two ranges of which one is amended dynamically (by iterator).

Comment: @Al_Iskander - just give a screenshot with a fake data. Something like "elephant", "tiger", "koala" etc.

Comment: `[]` is short for `Evaluate("")` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193019.aspx

Comment: @Slai, this was the missing link. When you use "Evaluate" then one can easily use the iterator without using the "formula" solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
With ActiveSheet
For i = 1 to 5
    .Range("c" & i & ":I" & i & "").formula = "=INDEX(EURbased!C" & i & ":I" & i & " * EURbased!C4:I4,0)"
Next
End With
```

I have not tried it myself, but as far as you mentioned `I would like to use iterator i instead of the "5" in EURbased!C5:I5` I think it should work.

Comment: typing comment on a phone is a bit frustrating for me so I hoped you wouldn't mind :]

Comment: actually I am impressed by the people who can put value into SO through a phone! :) +50 :)